# Munin/Nginx - Nginx prepending root path to file despite different path specifed with alias

Tags: nginx, munin

I have installed munin (for the time being available here: http://brailsford.xyz/munin ) the problem is that whilst the core loads from /var/cache/munin/www - none o the static files load.

I have the following in my nginx config:

```
    location /munin/static/ {
            alias /etc/munin/static/;
            expires modified +1w;
            autoindex on;
    }

    location /munin/ {
            #auth_basic            "Restricted";
            # Create the htpasswd file with the htpasswd tool.
            #auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/htpasswd;

            alias /var/cache/munin/www/;
            expires modified +310s;
    }
```

AutoIndex is there for a proof: the folder is accessible: https://brailsford.xyz/munin/static/

However, clicking on a file in that folder gives a 404, and the nginx error log shows this:

```
[error] 22570#0: *50 open() "/data/www/brailsford.xyz/munin/static/style-new.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

/data/www/brailsford.xyz is my root specified in the overall server clause.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT 1:

```
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff)$ {
            expires 1w;
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you use `location /munin/static/(.*)$` and `alias /etc/munin/static/$1;`?

Comment: Do you have a regex location matching `.css` files?

Comment: Still picks up the wrong path  directory index of "/var/cache/munin/www/static/" is forbidden @kyl191

Comment: @RichardSmith Only for expiry - see the location block I just added in my edit.

Comment: That will do it. Location blocks are not additive in `nginx`. Try `location ^~ /munin/static/ { ... }` which will make it override any regex location (hopefully there are no PHP files in there).

Comment: @RichardSmith that did it, do you want to post your comment as an answer? I have another problem now with the graphs not loading - think it's looking in the wrong place, I'll look at that one later :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff)$` block takes precedence for any URIs which end with `.css`, which means that `nginx` tries to use the wrong value for `root`.

Use the `^~` modifier on the prefix `location` to make it take precedence over any regex location.

For example:

```
location ^~ /munin/static/ { 
    ...
}
```

This assumes that the location does not have any special content, such as `.php` files.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: This saved my bacon, kept looking all over why the location alias was being overwritten and this was what fixed it. When trying to implement xsendfile for Moodle.